# How to add a "dummy" user to a board?

Tags: trello

I want to manage a Trello board with a bunch of users on it, but I don't actually want the users to participate, I just want to be able to assign them to things. Is there a way to add fictive ("dummy/mock", if you prefer) users to my board, just to easily manage their assignments to cards, but without inviting actual people?

Alternatively, if there's no such option, is there another way I can approximate this (e.g. defining each student as a card and association a card with another card)?

---

Background: I occasionally supervise students' projects. Trello seems really useful for me to track which project is at what stage and which students are assigned to what, but the projects are not necessarily related and I don't actually want the students to participate in this high-level management, it's just intended for me and my fellow grad students / faculty members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trello doesn't have this feature, unfortunately....
I have a similar situation, and the only way I can think of is to manually create real users
The only trick I've found is that you can use a single gmail address for multiple accounts by adding periods to it. eg:

```
myname@gmail.com
m.yname@gmail.com
m.y.name@gmail.com
m.y.n.ame@gmail.com
```

Trello will treat them as unique addresses, but gmail will treat them as the same.

I know it's not much but at least it's something...

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I'm guessing it will also treat emails with "+" (e.g. myemail+student1@gmail.com) as separate - in which case, this can be a relatively simple way to create multiple users without needing multiple addresses.

Comment: That's a really nice solution.