# Create private labels on Trello

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I am using Trello to track bug fixes in my company.

I'm using labels for my cards in order to categorize them, but I would also like to create labels that only I can see.  Is it possible?

I want to create deeper categories but it'll be only useful to me. I don't want to have too many labels flooding the interface to the other users.

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26629

Comment: @jonsca it's not what I'm looking for. I still want my team to be able to edit cards, I just want to keep some labels for me.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not a duplicate, but it had been proposed as a duplicate via a flag, so I dropped the link in just to link the two questions in the sidebar ->